# R, create a new column in a data frame that applies a function of all the columns with similar names

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in which the names of the columns are something like a,b,v1,v2,v3...v100.
I want to create a new column that applies a function to only the columns whose names include 'v'.

For example, given this data frame

```
df<-data.frame(a=rnorm(3),v1=rnorm(3),v2=rnorm(3),v3=rnorm(3))
```

I want to create a new column in which each element is the sum of the elements of v1, v2 and v3 that are in the same row.

Answer (score 6):

`grep` on `names` to get the column positions, then use `rowSums`:

```
rowSums(df[,grep("v",names(df))])
```

Comment: Use `df[grep("v",names(df))]` to avoid conversion to vector if only one column is selected. Compare `df[,"v1"]` vs `df["v1"]`.

Answer (score 3):

To combine both @James's and @Anatoliy's answers,

```
apply(df[grepl('^v', names(df))], 1, sum)
```

I went ahead and anchored the v in the regular expression to the beginning of the string.  Other examples haven't done that but it appears that you want all columns that begin with v not the larger set that may have a v in their name.  If I am wrong you could just do

```
apply(df[grepl('v', names(df))], 1, sum)
```

You should avoid using `subset()` when programming, as stated in `?subset`

> This is a convenience function intended for use interactively.  For
>   programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like
>   ‘[’, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument
>   ‘subset’ can have unanticipated consequences.

Also, as I learned yesterday [from Richie Cotton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381932/names-of-r-packages/7385535#7385535), when indexing it is better to use `grepl` than `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

That should do:

```
df$sums<- rowSums(subset(df, select=grepl("v", names(df))))
```

For a more general approach:

```
apply(subset(df, select=grepl("v", names(df))), 1, sum)
```