# How do I create a package name with underscore?

Tags: r

I get this error when running `devtools::check()`.

```
Error in processx::run(bin, args = real_cmdargs, stdout_line_callback = real_callback(stdout),  : 
  System command error
```

The check runs and completes just fine if I remove the underscore from my package name. How do I create a package name with underscore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual on writing R extensions describes that this is not permitted.

> The mandatory ‘Package’ field gives the name of the package. This should contain only (ASCII) letters, numbers and dot, have at least two characters and start with a letter and not end in a dot. If it needs explaining, this should be done in the ‘Description’ field (and not the ‘Title’ field).

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Creating-R-packages

See also this question: [What's a good R package name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201568/whats-a-good-r-package-name)

Comment: This is so weird! I am curious as to why. I suppose this is also imposed on R packages not distributed on CRAN.